# Merging two datasets into a new entity

Tags: mysql, database-design, merge, dataset

I am new to all this and struggling to get my head around some of the conundrums thrown up. My area of interest is `census data`. What I am currently doing is taking the data from a `1901 and a 1911 censuses and merging` them into a new database. I then ascertain that a particular person is actually the same person on both censuses, once I am certain that 1901 Jack Thelad (aged 31) with ID 55 is the same as 1911 Jack Thelad (aged 41) with ID 777 what is the best way to deal with the primary key issue?

```
1901 Jack Thelad ID55
1911 Jack Thelad ID777
MergedCensus Jack Thelad ID???
```

Should I look on the primary key as  like a social security number, allocate Jack Thelad a number in my MergedCensus and then copy that number back into the 1901 and 1911 data effectively overwriting ID55 and ID77?

Answer (score 0):

in this new database which i assume you are designing, could u have a table that was:

newId |  name       |  1901id | 1911id |
------|-------------|---------|--------|
1234  | Jack Thelad | ID55    | ID77   |

and then you could search

```
 SELECT data,data,data from newtable,1901id,1911id where newtable.1901id=1901table.id
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that information and apologies for not replying earlier but I was away all last week. I will try out your suggestion.